# How to prove that the subset of a language L that is in P is also in P?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

Given that $L∈\textrm{P}$, how do we show that an arbitrary subset $L_{A}$ of $L$ is also in P?

Comment: A general hint I encountered here years ago: whenever asked how to do something for  arbitrary languages $L$, first consider the cases $L = \emptyset$ and $L = \Sigma^*$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot show that, since the claim is false.
Let $L = \Sigma^*$ and let $L_A \subset \Sigma^*$ be the language of the halting problem. Clearly $L \in \mathsf{P}$ (a Turing machine that decides $L$ is the one that ignores its input and immediately accepts). However $L_A$ is well-known to be undecidable (and hence not in $\mathsf{P}$).

Answer (score 1):

By $\textrm{P}$ do you mean the languages that are decidable in polynomial time? If so, I am pretty sure this isn't true. For example, let $L$ be the language of graphs that are 2-edge-connected, and $L_A$ the language of graphs that contain Hamiltonian cycles. Then $L \in \textrm{P}$ and $L_A \subseteq L$ but $L_A \not\in \textrm{P}$, unless $\textrm{P} = \textrm{NP}$.

Comment: Why do you say that $L_A \not\in \mathsf{P}$? It is currently unknown whether $L_A \in \mathsf{P}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant that it is believed that $L_A \not\in \textrm{P}$ and if the original question's claim were true it would show that $\textrm{P} = \textrm{NP}$. Your answer is a more concrete refutation.